# Is it possible to grant access for a domain group in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to set up TeamCity with Windows Authentication but can't find any documentation about configuring a TeamCity to only allow login for a specific AD-group, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with Windows Domain authentication. Try TeamCity LDAP authentication instead which is more capable and supports AD. It still can require some effort and trial and error approach to configure correctly. Here is an [example](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Typical+LDAP+Configurations#TypicalLDAPConfigurations-BasicLDAPLoginforUsersinaSpecificLDAPGroupOnly) of allowing only a single AD group to login.

Comment: Great, thank you. Will see if I will use it thought. Used a worked around where all users only got project view rights as defaults instead which works as good for now.